# .htaccess isn't loading static html pages in additional domain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I'm having problems to browse normal html pages inside my additional domain, example-domain.com

here's my file structure

```
public_html
        -css
        -img  
        -js
        example-domain.com              <- get server error
                          - index.html    
                          -products.html   
                          - contact.html
        -system
         .htaccess  
         index.php
```

I use codeigniter framework in the main site, and simple html within the additional domain
example-domain.com , when i put the url to browse example-domain.com, i get a 500 internal server error I think it's due to my .htaccess file i 'm using for the main domain. How can I modify it to load simple .html files inside my additional domain as well.

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|uploads|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just add `|exampledomain\.com` into `RewriteCond` section.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, what I see, you are trying to do the redirect, if the requested URL is not a file and not a directory. It can be done, using these directives:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more on what is incorrect. I use identical `RewriteCond` & `RewriteRule` statements for all my codeigniter sites and have never had a problem.

Comment: If your interested, this is a pretty simple explanation of why $1 does work in `RewriteCond`. http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4330396.htm

Comment: @Jeemusu Very interesting. Once I tried to use forward references in .htaccess, but they didn't work. And I decided, it's impossible to use. Thank you, I removed incorrect statement from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```